# A question about the symmetric idempotent matrices.

Tags: statistics

I am reading the paper ["Least Squares Model Averaging"](https://www.ssc.wisc.edu/%7Ebhansen/papers/mallows.pdf) written by Professor Bruce E. Hansen. In the page 9, the writer has the following observations.

> Note that for $l\leq m$, $P_l P_m = P_l$ and $(I-P_m)b_l=(I-P_m)b_m$

Here, $X_l$ and $X_m$ are $n\times k_l$ and $n\times k_m$ matrices, respectively, which satisfies the following restrictions:

(1) $k_m$ and $k_l$ are numbers related with $m$ and $l$, which satisfies $k_l\le k_m$ if $l\le m$.

(2) If $l\le m$, then $X_m=(X_l,Y_{k_m-k_l})$, where $Y_{k_m-k_l}$ is a $n\times(k_m-k_l)$ matrix.

Finally, set $$P_l=X_l(X_l^{'}X_l)^{-1}X_l^{'}~~~\text{and}~~~P_m=X_m(X_m^{'}X_m)^{-1}X_m^{'},~~l\le m.$$

I have tried to check these observations by direct calculations. But the calculations are too complicated. So I want to know whether we have some simple ways to obtain these. I would be grateful if anyone can help me.

Comment: I have edited your question by replacing the link to the image by the actual text of the image, do you agree with my edit ? Note that it is much more readable to have the full description of the question in the body and not on external sources. Also note that there is no definition of $b_m$ and $b_l$ in your question.

Comment: @P.Quinton Thanks very much! It seems better to read!

Answer (score 1):

Observe that for $\ell\leq m$, we have
\begin{align*}
X_\ell^T X_m &= X_\ell^T\cdot \begin{bmatrix}
X_\ell&Y_{k_m-k_\ell}
\end{bmatrix}\\
&=\begin{bmatrix}
X_\ell^T X_\ell&X_\ell^T Y_{k_m-k_\ell}
\end{bmatrix}
\end{align*}
and
\begin{align*}
X_m^T X_m &= \begin{bmatrix}
X_\ell^T\\Y_{k_m-k_\ell}^T
\end{bmatrix}\cdot \begin{bmatrix}
X_\ell&Y_{k_m-k_\ell}
\end{bmatrix}\\
&=\begin{bmatrix}
X_\ell^T X_\ell&X_\ell^T Y_{k_m-k_\ell}\\
Y_{k_m-k_\ell}^TX_\ell&Y_{k_m-k_\ell}^TY_{k_m-k_\ell}
\end{bmatrix}
\end{align*}
therefore $X_\ell^T X_m$ is a submatrix of $X_m^T X_m$. Now since $X_m^T X_m (X_m^T X_m)^{-1}=I_{k_m}$, this means that $X_\ell^T X_m (X_m^T X_m)^{-1}=\begin{bmatrix} I_{k_\ell}&0_{k_\ell,k_m-k_\ell}\end{bmatrix}$ where $0_{a,b}$ is the zero matrix of dimension $a\times b$. Multiplying this by $X_m^T$ on the right gives
\begin{align*}
X_\ell^T X_m (X_m^T X_m)^{-1} X_m^T &= \begin{bmatrix} I_{k_\ell}&0_{k_\ell,k_m-k_\ell}\end{bmatrix}\cdot \begin{bmatrix} 
X_\ell^T\\Y_{k_m-k_\ell}
\end{bmatrix}\\
&=X_\ell^T
\end{align*}
therefore $P_\ell P_m=P_\ell$.

I didn't check in the paper the definition of $b_m$ and $b_\ell$ but I think similar reasoning by breaking the matrices in the corresponding blocks and being careful about the operations would give the right result.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I will use your hint to try to prove the second identity by myself!